# I am trying to write a class for select query but datatable throws an error why?

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to write a class for a select query but `DataTable` throws an error - why?

```
    public DataTable show(string select)
    {
        return "DataTable";
    }
```

Comment: 1) Your return type is `DataTable` but you return `"DataTable"` which is `string`. 2) Your `select` parameter seems useless. Your question is not clear at all. What is the error by the way?

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: the type or name space name 'DataTable' could notbe found

Answer (score 3):

try this -

```
public DataTable show(string select)
    {
     Datatable dt=new DataTable();       

     return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a `string`, not a `Datatable` object

Without any other context all I can advise is to either change the return type of the method the `string`

```
public string show(string select)
{
    return "DataTable";
}
```

OR

return a datatable object by creating one in the method

```
public DataTable show(string select)
{
 Datatable table = new DataTable();       

 //Do stuff here     

 return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code-:

you ruturn string "Datatable" not datatable so please try this

```
 public DataTable show(string query)
    {
     string strcon = @"Data Source=client-2;Initial Catalog=Name;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";          
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;      
   SqlConnection     con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
   con.Open();
   string qry = "Select * from Dbname";
   da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, strcon);
   dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);                            
   return dt;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the return type of the method is `DataTable` the method must return `Datatable` as you are returning `string` you are getting the error.

**Try this:**

```
public DataTable Show(string selectQuery) {
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString)) {
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, cn);
           da.Fill(dt);
      }
      return dt;
}
```